# Change emulation back when navigating off page - angular javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, encapsulation

I have the following code in my component.ts file on one particular page, because that page needs to use it's own css for when the page is printed:

```
@Component({
  selector: "dashboard",
  templateUrl: "./dashboard.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./dashboard.component.scss"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

However, when i navigate off that page, i want the encapsulation to go back to normal for everywhere else. Is there a way to do this?

Or is there a way to only set the encapsulation when the print button is clicked? And then when closed it goes back to normal?

If I navigate away from this page and refresh, then the other pages go back to normal, but I don't want to have to refresh.

EDIT

I had to add in the encapsulation in order to get the page to print landscape using this code in the scss file:

```
@media print {
    @page {
      size: landscape 
    }
    .no-print,
    .no-print * {
      display: none !important;
    }
    body {
      -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    }
    canvas {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    .printClass {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
```

Otherwise, it would just take the global scss and print portrait every time.

Comment: Show your animation code. By the way: You can add public css animations in styles.scss. And with ngClass you can change classes if printing or not.

Comment: thanks @Flo. what do you mean by animation code? I have added my scss code which wasn't working until i added the encapsulation. The only problem is when i navigate off this page, i want the encapsulation to go back to normal (emulated) for all the other pages

Comment: ok, no animations, only styles. I understand. So encapsulation stop to affect the rest of the application. So you use the "same" classes (so class names) in many components, right?

Comment: @flo, yes lots of pages are the same, but I just need to stop the global CSS affecting this one page, so I can change the print size to landscape

Comment: Why not using ngClass? Or use a extra component for the printing part

Comment: @Flo could you possibly give me an example of how I would do that? I am using window print() in my component and media print to set the size to landscape

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In this example we use `ngx-print`. This is a library you can see on [GitHub](https://github.com/selemxmn/ngx-print). You do not use it, but it is using the right way and it is very straight forward.

```
npm install ngx-print
```

*Using*

```
 <!--
   1)- Add an ID here
 -->
<div id="print-section"> 
  <!--Your html stuff that you want to print-->
</div>

 <!--
   2)- Add the directive name in your button (ngxPrint),
   3)- Affect your ID to printSectionId
 -->
<button printSectionId="print-section" ngxPrint>print</button>
```

You can set things in css. Here is a sample:

1. When I do not apply css using [useExistingCss]="true", the Layout dropdown option (portrait or landscape) is present when trying to print.
2. My css contains a @media print{@page {size: landscape}} line, but it seems to be ignored by ngx-print.
3. If I use {size: landscape !important}, it will print in landscape.
4. If I use {size: auto !important}, the Layout option is provided.

Here is the **heart** of it:

```
public print(): void {
    let printContents, popupWin, styles = '', links = '';
    const baseTag = this.getElementTag('base');

    if(this.useExistingCss) {
      styles = this.getElementTag('style');
      links = this.getElementTag('link');
    }

    printContents = this.getHtmlContents();
    popupWin = window.open("", "_blank", "top=0,left=0,height=auto,width=auto");
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>${this.printTitle ? this.printTitle : ""}</title>
          ${baseTag}
          ${this.returnStyleValues()}
          ${this.returnStyleSheetLinkTags()}
          ${styles}
          ${links}
        </head>
        <body>
          ${printContents}
          <script defer>
            function triggerPrint(event) {
              window.removeEventListener('load', triggerPrint, false);
              ${this.previewOnly ? '' : `setTimeout(function() {
                closeWindow(window.print());
              }, ${this.printDelay});`}
            }
            function closeWindow(){
                window.close();
            }
            window.addEventListener('load', triggerPrint, false);
          </script>
        </body>
      </html>`);
    popupWin.document.close();
```

Comment: Hi, I don't think ngx print is compatible with my app, I am getting lots of errors. Is there any other method? Thanks in advance

Comment: The code snipe I showed (the heart) is what you need. This is the standard code to printing in javascript/browser.